# Can I prepare an Ubuntu SD card for my Pi 2 B on a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: sd-card, windows, ubuntu, windows-iot

The title says it all. Can I find and can I flash the correct Pi image for Ubuntu (apparently the only Linux the 2 B can use so far)?

Then, is there guidence for this anywhere?

Or must I first get an Ubuntu VM up on my Windows machine?

PS, This section on the [Embedded Linux Wiki](http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions#Available_ARMv7_distributions) gave me the impression that the only distributions for the ARMv7, and I wasn't sure about backward compatibility:

[image]

Comment: Yes you can.  Raspbian, Fedora, Debian, Arch Linux have long worked on the Pis including the Pi2.  They are all Linux.  What gives you the idea that Ubuntu was the first?  It only works on the Pi2.

Comment: @joan you should form that as an answer since it is correct.
OP, you seem to have been misinformed

Comment: @joan - OP's question is about how to flash it (though your comment is perfectly correct) for which I assume the normal Windows flash instructions using the disk imager software would do the trick, as Windows 10 is fully compatible with older Windows versions such as 7 and 8.

Comment: @joan, the **Embedded Linux Wiki**[1] gave me the idea that Ubuntu and Windows 10 were the only distributions up to date with the ARMv7. See my edits for what gave me that impression. I was looking for an OS for the ARMv7, not older.

Comment: @ProfK That does explain the confusion. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I have experienced with that. you will not get any issues flashing linux from windows 10.

Comment: Any hints how, what tool?

Comment: You should explain how to do this with a link to full instructions.

Comment: @ProfK this should help with flashing an image to the SD card http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup or https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/

Comment: Use win32 Disk imager
Select the image file and the drive
click write button
as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the image file, I use either CygWin or a Linux (Ubuntu) VM on VMWare to do the actual writing.

Some *n*x experience required, for both methods.

CygWin is the fastest to launch on Windows because it doesn't have to boot an OS, but it doesn't support sparse files. You do need to start it as UAC admin to get write access to the raw disk.

A Linux VM will give the fastest write if the image is delivered as a sparse file combined with a .bmap file that maps which sectors do not have to be written to flash because they're unused. Use bmaptool to do the writing.

I have also tried to use the new 'Bash on Ubuntu on Windows' add-on to Windows 10, but no luck there so far.